# What is the carrier of push and pull force?

Tags: forces

Suppose I push a book with my hand. I am applying force on it in the process. My question is: What is the carrier of the force I am applying?

Comment: Electromagnetic fields.

Answer (score 0):

It is the mutual repulsion of the electron clouds that closely surround the molecules and atoms that make up your skin.